# Mule ESB How to manage multiple project?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, mule-esb

I have a base project named : ParentProject that contains all common businesses needed for children. 
I also have 2 children Child1Project and Child2Project those project inherit all businesses of the ParentProject.

In the future, I may have Child3Project, Child4Project, so on.

So what should I do to organize those project in MULE ESB 3.7?

Many thanks.

Comment: you can compile your project as a jar file then add it as dependencies wherever you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this will be to make sure all your projects use Maven as build tool. Now, while creating the POM for the parent project, make sure it's packaging is "jar". Now, whenever you want too add this parent project properties to your child project, you'll just need to import the jar to the child project, or the repository configuration of the parent project in the POM of the child project.

Comment: I have packaged jar file and import it into child project so now, How can i use the flow reference component to refer to a parent flow?

Comment: I Hope once you loaded your jar file in the flow ref component you will be populated with list of flows from there you can refer to the existing flow'

Comment: Along with the procedure in @vijaydhanakodi's comment, you will also have to make sure that you import the configuration xml of the parent flow that you want to refer in the child flow. So, in a nutshell, in the child configuration file, you will need to add the below syntax after the namespaces                                                                        `<spring:beans>
       <spring:import resource="classpath:<parentconfiguration>.xml"/></spring:beans>`